# Create a jQuery function for on click

Tags: jquery

I need to create a function that I can call with .on("click")

So far I have...

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    createCase: function () {
            alert('smeg');
     } 
});

$("#results").on("click", ".cancel_case_btn").createCase();
```

All this does is alert 'smeg' when the page opens and does nothing when the element is clicked

Comment: So, what is your question? What is the behavior? What are the error messages?

Comment: Did you consider reading the documentation?

Comment: @EddeAlmeida the behaviour is it alerts when the page is opened and does nothing when the button is pressed and there are no errors just like I said in the question

Comment: @Amit yes I did, before I posted the question here

Comment: So what makes you think *that's* how `on` works?

Comment: I am learning, you must have been there once?

Comment: We have all been there once, @tatty27. But let's attack the problem, not each other. This on("click", ...) passing just a class in wrong. You must pass a function name for it to work.

Comment: It's OK to be learning, it's OK to misunderstand, but that doesn't explain what made you think that's how things work. If you saw that somewhere - add this context, that's why I asked. If you "made this up" because that's how you *want* it to be, there's a bigger lesson for you to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delegate the click event on the element so that once the respective item is clicked, you can invoke the function you created to be used with jquery objects.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    createCase: function () {
            alert('smeg');
     } 
});

$("#results").on("click",".cancel_case_btn", function()
{
  $(this).createCase();
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/fvgLd018/3/

Comment: Great. Glad to help :)

Comment: What good reason do you have to construct an event handler like this? Why not keep it simple like other answers suggest?

Comment: You can certainly extend the functionality by accessing the object using 'this' inside the created function.. The answer was provided for what was being asked.

Answer (score 2):

why not simply do something like this?

```
var createCase = function () {
  alert('smeg');
};


$("#results").on("click", ".cancel_case_btn", createCase);
```

Comment: I think his intention is to create user-defined jquery function that can be attached to a jqeury object.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do this the way you're thinking. When you invoke `.on`, you have to pass a function as the final parameter to register the callback for the onclick event.

You can still extend jquery with a new function if you like, but you'll need to register your callback within that function like so:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    registerCreateCaseClickHandler: function () {
        $(this).on("click", function() {
            // do whatever you want
        }
        //register any other events you care about
    }
});
```

Then you would use it like so:

```
$("#results .cancel_case_btn").registerCreateCaseClickHandler();
```

Of course this is really overkill to create an extension. It would be easier to just define the `createCase` function and pass in as the callback to the `.on` event as intended like this:

```
function createCase() {
    var clickedButton = $(this);
    // do stuff
}

$("#results").on("click", ".cancel_case_btn", createCase);
```